# Python Pandas: Use regex to replace strings with hyperlink

Tags: python, regex, pandas, replace, hyperlink

Beginner's question.

I'm scraping housing ads with BS4 and analyse the subsequent data with Pandas.

I have a DataFrame with several columns. This issue considers only one of the columns, which looks like,

```
district | ... |
----------------
   A     | ... |
   B     | ... |
   C     | ... |
  ...    | ... |
```

I have a list of links related to the districts. For e.g. district A, the link looks like `www.site.com/city/district-A/`.

I want to replace each district name in the column (e.g. "A") with `<a href="www.site.com/city/district-A/">A</a>`. Preferably I do this replacement using regular expressions, since I have a large variety of district names and district links.

To make it more difficult, the district names are non-ASCII, while the links are ASCII.

How do I go about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seem you need `apply` `format`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'district':['A','B','C']})

df['url'] = df.district.apply('<a href="www.site.com/city/district-{0}/">{0}</a>'.format)
print (df)
  district                                            url
0        A  <a href="www.site.com/city/district-A/">A</a>
1        B  <a href="www.site.com/city/district-B/">B</a>
2        C  <a href="www.site.com/city/district-C/">C</a>
```

Comment: Thank you! It took a while before I got it to work – I wasn't using dictionaries.

Comment: So, I'm pretty close. Though, do you know a way to convert the `A` in `/district-A/` to ASCII characters? I need `A` in the link to be ASCII but the link name `A` to be non-ASCII. Now both are non-ASCII – the names are ok but the links won't work...

Comment: Now I am offline, only on phone, but is possible use some convertor to ASCII from non ASCII? I never converted some text this way, so hard help you. :(

Answer (score -1):

Why not

```
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
     A = row['column']
     new = '<a href="www.site.com/city/district-{A}/">{A}</a>'.format(A=A)
     df[idx, 'column'] = new
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! However, I did not get it to work :(